# Set global environment variable on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, environment-variables, launchd, macos-big-sur, ssh-agent

**What I want to achive:**
I need to use OpennSSH SSH agent instead of default Mac OS SSH agent. For this purpose I unloaded **com.openssh.ssh-agent** launchd and created my own custom plist file. It works well. It creates socket file ~/.ssh/agent. All I need further is just set environment variable SSH_SOCK_AUTH and ssh agent works as I expect.

**What is the issue:**
In terminal it's all right. I added `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/agent.sock` to **.zprofile** and I can use ssh agent. The issue comes when I want to use ssh agent in some GUI applications. They "doesn't know" about SSH_AUTH_SOCK. So ssh agent doesn't work.

**What I tried to do:**
I created another plist file and executed there the following code:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/agent.sock;launchctl setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK ~/.ssh/agent.sock;date>~/test_set_env
```

It doesn't work. Meanwhile, as you can see, I added a piece of code which create file in home dir and add current date there. I did it to check whether code on plist file work at all. **And file created! **So, it means that code works****, but on the boot, in any session SSH_AUTH_SOCK is steel doesn't set (without usage of .zprofile).

Please let me some hint. How can I set environment variable on Mac OS Big Sur ?

There are tons of articles how to do it, but all described methods doesn't work on Big Sur.

Comment: You might try using the actual absolute path rather than `-` in those commands, e.g. `/Users/YOURNAME` You may also need to log out and back in for changes to take effect.